# Gdb not catching kernel panic

Tags: linux-kernel, android-emulator, gdb, kernel, qemu

I have an ARM Linux kernel running as part of the android emulator where I'm doing a bit of testing. I start the emulator without the GUI stuff, and just use adb shell to access the emulator's internal memory.

I start up the emulator on an OSX machine as follows :-

```
$ emulator -verbose -debug init -show-kernel -kernel ./zImage -avd debug -no-boot-anim -no-skin -no-audio -no-window -qemu -gdb tcp::1234
```

I attach gdb to the emulator as follows :-

```
$ arm-eabi-gdb ./vmlinux
(gdb) target remote :1234
```

I know that the attaching works well, because if I attach the debugger earlier on, I can see that the boot process pauses till I press "c" in gdb. However, when a kernel panic arises in the emulator, I see a stack trace on the terminal that runs the emulator -- however, I don't see any change on the gdb side. The machine halts when the kernel panics, so I'd assume that gdb would show some indication of the same. Why doesn't this happen?

When I Ctrl-C at the emulator side to stop QEMU, I get the message `emulator: Done with QEMU main loop. emulator: User-config was not changed.` and gdb shows `Remote connection closed`.

What as I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Placing a breakpoint on panic and inspecting the backtrace is a possible solution to the problem.